Next js server side component not able to complete fetch request in GCP cloud run
There is no any CORS related error in log and it's work in local build environment, request source indicate Next.js Middleware
here it is
"GET /blogs/list/get HTTP/1.1" 200 1232 "-" "Next.js Middleware"
but there is no log in production environment for the same api and no request at all, is there any specific configuration I shall make?
I wwant this fetch request from server side component to work in production/GCP cloud run.
UPDATE: I checked my nginx log, there is no any error, it's not even able to hit the server.

Can you elaborate on your issue? What do the logs show? Are you getting any error messages? Also can you please share the logs?

What's your architecture? WHat did you have deployed? Where and when the issue occur?

the error message is: "TypeError: fetch failed"
in gcp cloud run log,
i have deployed a nextjs app on gcp cloud run, with some server component which fetches data,

Did you find the fix

Solved!
Previously my runtime variable in layout file wa set as :
export const runtime = "edge";

Now I changed it to :
export const runtime = "nodejs";

and it works!
